# Python Django Class based views - accessing data

Tags: python, django

I've created a ListView

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ReportListView(ListView):
    model = ReportList
    context_object_name = 'reportitems'
    template_name = "reports.html"

# urls.py
path('reports/', login_required(views.ReportListView.as_view()),
```

However, when I try to check length of `reportitems` I get this error

`` `Could not parse the remainder: '(reportitems)' from 'len(reportitems)' ``

`# my html file`

`{{ len(reportitems) }}  or  {{ len(object_list) }}`

I get the same error with `object_list` too. What am I doing wrong? Just to confirm. `ReportList` model doesn't have any data in it. Is that the reason it's failing? If yes, how could I check that if there is any data or not yet?

I tried to look at Django docs and Google search. However, it seems like I should have access to `object_list` variable or unless when I change it's name.

Comment: Try {{ reportitems|length }} ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#length))

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Yes, it worked! Thanks. Does this mean standard Python methods don't work in templates? I'm learning.

Comment: @Danny Yeah, that's right. In the templates, you use something called Jinja2 and that's django pass data from server to the template

Comment: @OliverHnat Thanks for pointing that out! Is there any way to make it work inside templates (not that I need it, but in case I need something in future)?

Comment: jinja2 / django use a template engine.  The syntax is different but there is rich functionality.  Django's documentation is excellent, and I recommend reading through that.

Comment: @Danny to address more advanced requirements, you can use template tags and filters. Check the documentation for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/